# Laravel Route in JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, laravel, routes

I have the below section of my js file but instead of hard code http://127.0.0.1:8000/Edit/Fee/Category/1. I need to Pass laravel route like this

```
{{route('Edit.Fee.Category',$Category->id)}}
```

```html
var initTable5 = function() {
        var table = $('#kt_datatable5');

        // begin first table
        table.DataTable({
            scrollY: '450vh',
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            columnDefs: [{
                    targets: -1,
                    title: 'Actions',
                    orderable: false,
                    width: '125px',
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '\
                            \
                            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Edit/Fee/Category/1" class="btn btn-hover-bg-primary btn-text-primary btn-hover-text-white border-0 font-weight-bold mr-2">Click To Pay</a>\
                            \
                        ';
                    },
                },
            ],
        });
    };
```

Comment: Is this code  exists in a blade file?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Comment: If your JS is within a `.blade.php` file then you can simply do this: `return '{{route('Edit.Fee.Category',$Category->id)}}';`

Comment: No the js file is separate from the blade file hence the challenge I am having

Comment: its wired but you can assign your laravel route to a js variable and then you can use that variable in external js file. Make sure that js variable should be assigned before you load your actual js file.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciated.